Visual Studio Code doesn't display visualized Qt5 objects on Linux
Using VSCode 1.85.2.
I have qt5.natvis on my Linux CentOS 7, and my launch.json file includes the following properties:
{    
    ...
    "visualizerFile": "/path/to/qt5.natvis",
    "showDisplayString": true
}

While breaking into cpp code, I can only see visualized QString-s but not other objects like QStringList. For those, in the watch window I get the error "-var-create: unable to create variable object".
By the way, viewing the QString became available only after adding the "showDisplayString" property.
The same natvis works fine on Windows, Visual Studio 2015.
Any idea on how to fix this or if there's any alternative?
